# How do I fix this import?

Tags: go

main_test.go

```
package main_test

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "testing"
    "."
)

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    a = main.App{}
    a.Init(
        os.Getenv("TEST_DB_USERNAME"),
        os.Getenv("TEST_DB_PASSWORD"),
        os.Getenv("TEST_DB_NAME"))

    ensureTableExists()
    code := m.Run()
    clearTable()
    os.Exit(code)
}
```

app.go

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type App struct {
    Router *mux.Router
    DB *sql.DB
}

func (a *App) Init(user, password, dbname string) {

    connection := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s", user, password, dbname)
    var err error
    a.DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", connection)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    a.Router = mux.NewRouter()

}
func (a *App) Run(addr string) { }
```

main.go

```
package main

import "os"

func main() {
    a := App{}
    a.Init(
        os.Getenv("APP_DB_USERNAME"),
        os.Getenv("APP_DB_PASSWORD"),
        os.Getenv("APP_DB_NAME"))
    a.Run(":8080")
}
```

Hey everyone, I am brand new to Golang and working with some tutorials. In the tutorial, they are using the import statement "." which is throwing an error for me. The exact error is "Non-canonical import-path." I tried using a relative path and full path to access the main file in my project but when I use anything other than "." the var a.main.App throws an error saying that main is an unresolved type. My $GOPATH is set to c:/users/me/go/src my project lives in the src folder. I am not entirely sure what is wrong my code at the moment. If it is something glaringly obvious I apologize.

Here is what I am trying to import. This lives in a file called app.go which is called through main.go

```
type App struct {
    Router *mux.Router
    DB *sql.DB
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to import?

Comment: a struct named App that contains a mux.Router and a DB *sql.DB command.

Comment: You can't import ".". In go, you don't import files like in c/c++ but you import packages instead. If your file is in the main package, no import statement is required.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense to me the problem is when I try to use that struct in my test file I get an error saying unresolved type. It is not recognizing it for some reason. @Ullaakut

Comment: Edit your question and add all of the relevant code, we will help you figure out what's wrong

Comment: is it both `app.go` and `main.go` lives into same package like `package main` or both files lived into diffrent packages?

Comment: edited the OP with all files and source code now. main.go and app.go lie within the same package main_test.go does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to import main for using struct `App`. You simply change the package of `main_test` to `main` then you can able to use that struct, like below i simply passed the `main_test` file.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    a := App{}
    a.Init(
        os.Getenv("TEST_DB_USERNAME"),
        os.Getenv("TEST_DB_PASSWORD"),
        os.Getenv("TEST_DB_NAME"))

    ensureTableExists()
    code := m.Run()
    clearTable()
    os.Exit(code)
}
```

Here what i get from execute the test:

```
Success: Tests passed.
```